# How to show our application icon on blackberry device menu item?

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I have developed one phonegap blackberry application.

I got sign key and successfully installed to blackberry device also.

But when I close my app, again I want to open that app means, that app icon is not there in my blackberry device.But it's showing on simulator.

So, How to show that icon to my Blackberry device menu item?

Please let me know...

Comment: I didn't get really. You cam't find your app on the device? How did you installed it?

Comment: Did you check `Downloads` folder ? It should be there.

Answer (score 1):

The icon file should be provided in a resources folder in your project. Depending on how you package your app, the icon is provided in a zip file you create yourself if using the Webworks SDK, or the zip file is created by Ripple.

It depends on which OS you are using to where it places the app, downloads for OS 5.0 and all applications for other OS, which is where you will see the icon.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing an app in Eclipse,then you need to go to Blackberry_App_Descriptor.xml and select in that Blackberry_App_Descriptor.xml page , Add image in Application Icon's,that will be your application icon. Now go to Downloads on BB Device and find your app icon,Click it to start your App

Comment: Thank you friends...I found it on downloads folder to my BlackBerry device